# How old was Jatayu when he fought Ravana?

Tags: ramayana, ravana, jatayu

[Jatayu](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jatayu) in Ramayana was a vulture who fought against Ravana, while the latter was abducting Sita.

What was Jatayu's age during his fight against Ravana?

Comment: I don't think his age is mentioned in Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa, I haven't read it.

Answer (score 3):

When Jatayu fought Ravana he was sixty thousand years old. He mentions his age in the Ramayana as follows:

> **षष्टिवर्षसहस्राणि जातस्य मम** रावण। पितृपैतामहं राज्यं यथावदनुतिष्ठतः॥२०॥
>
> **Sixty thousand years have elapsed, O Ravana, ever since I was born**, during which I have duly carried on the hereditary rulership of birds (my forefathers).
> -*Srimad Ramayana Aranyakanda, Chapter 50, verse 20*